# How to identify an Isolated Network

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, winverifytrust

I am developing a c# .Net3.5 application.

The applications checks the signature of files using [WinVerifyTrust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The problem is that on isolated networks (i.e. no Internet access but machine still has an IP address) it takes a very long time (~20 seconds) until WinVerifyTrust returns.

Is there a way to identify this situation?

Comment: You can prevent WinVerifyTrust from accessing the network. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46033461/winverifytrust-function-takes-long-time-to-excecute

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `Windows API`-

```
using System;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class InternetCS
    {
        //Creating the extern function...
        [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
        private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState( out int Description, int ReservedValue );

        //Creating a function that uses the API function...
        public static bool IsConnectedToInternet( )
        {
            int Desc ;
            return InternetGetConnectedState( out Desc, 0 ) ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

And how you will differentiate if the computer is connected with a slow internet connection?

Anyway you can Ping google (for example) to see if it's available. If the computer is not isolated it will be available.

To ping from C# just use System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping

**EDIT**: if you need to support being behind a proxy then you should open a TcpConnection over the google port 80 and check if you can or you cannot. If you cannot open a port to google's 80 you cannot connect to WinVerifyTrust either.

Comment: you are correct, but on a slow network connections it is ok that my application will work slowly, but when using isolated networks it's not.

Comment: I get request timeout when trying to ping google no matter if I am connected to the internet or not.

Comment: Can you post your code? I've done this several times in the past and it works. Can you check if you can ping google from the commandline too?

Comment: @user844541: so ... ? Comm'on :)

Comment: what?? I thought that maybe the firewall blocks the ping response . anyhow,my point is that ping can fail even if you have internet connection. so if ping failed it's not enough inorder to determine whether you're connected to the internet or not.

Comment: @user844541: you're wrong. If you cannot access google pinging it then you can be almost sure that you won't be able to access WinVerifyTrust. Nobody blocks outgoing traffic (even less if it's ICMP). The only possible scenario that I can think of is if you're on a proxy.