# How can I check programatically if my pc is behind a proxy?

Tags: c++, proxy, windows-networking

I'm trying to find a good way to determine if my pc is working behind a proxy or not.

I'm browsing through the WinAPI but cannot find anything useful. I´ve [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044352/how-to-identify-an-isolated-network/13044386#13044386) that it is enough to open a tcp connection on port 80 to an internet address but is this really the best solution?

I don't wanna check the proxy settings of each browser but the global system proxy settings ... if there is something like that.

I have to use Windows (XP and Windows 7 and newer should be supported) and C++

Comment: It's not an absolute thing. You may have a proxy for any subset of IP addresses, and possibly more than one. Different browsers may have different proxies. So, explain to your boss that no answer will be 100% correct anyway.

Comment: Ok, so I should edit my question ... I'm only interested in the system proxy settings.

Comment: You mean Internet Explorers settings? Note that in the EU, Windows "N" versions sometimes do not include IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WinINet API, see "Setting and Retrieving Internet Options" here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#general_option

This assumes the proxy setting is set in Internet Explorer options.

Comment: That's probably not a good fix, for some reason at my university IE runs without a proxy, whereas for example Firefox needs one. I wouldn't have a proxy set on IE.

Comment: @AdrianJandl I don't think that's possible.  The difference is that the university has set things up so that IE automatically uses the proxy, where as it's up to you to set up Firefox.

Comment: @JamesKanze: IE may run via MS ISA server acting as a firewall or NAT.