# WinVerifyTrust function takes long time to excecute

Tags: signtool, winverifytrust

I am using windows **WinVerifyTrust** function on *windows 10 pro*, to verify dll signatures.
when I activate this function for the first time, it takes **4 seconds** for the function to execute and return verification status for the first dll. for the other proceeding dlls, the function returns at fast rate.

Can anyone help me understand the possible reason for that latency?

the call that takes 4 sec is this call:

```
  lStatus = WinVerifyTrust(
        NULL,
        &WVTPolicyGUID,
        &WinTrustData);
```

The wraper function I'm using looks like this:

```
#define _UNICODE 1
#define UNICODE 1

#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Softpub.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <wintrust.h>

// Link with the Wintrust.lib file.
#pragma comment (lib, "wintrust")

BOOL VerifyEmbeddedSignature(LPCWSTR pwszSourceFile)
{
    LONG lStatus;
    DWORD dwLastError;

    // Initialize the WINTRUST_FILE_INFO structure.

    WINTRUST_FILE_INFO FileData;
    memset(&FileData, 0, sizeof(FileData));
    FileData.cbStruct = sizeof(WINTRUST_FILE_INFO);
    FileData.pcwszFilePath = pwszSourceFile;
    FileData.hFile = NULL;
    FileData.pgKnownSubject = NULL;


    GUID WVTPolicyGUID = WINTRUST_ACTION_GENERIC_VERIFY_V2;
    WINTRUST_DATA WinTrustData;

    // Initialize the WinVerifyTrust input data structure.

    // Default all fields to 0.
    memset(&WinTrustData, 0, sizeof(WinTrustData));

    WinTrustData.cbStruct = sizeof(WinTrustData);

    // Use default code signing EKU.
    WinTrustData.pPolicyCallbackData = NULL;

    // No data to pass to SIP.
    WinTrustData.pSIPClientData = NULL;

    // Disable WVT UI.
    WinTrustData.dwUIChoice = WTD_UI_NONE;

    // No revocation checking.
    WinTrustData.fdwRevocationChecks = WTD_REVOKE_NONE; 

    // Verify an embedded signature on a file.
    WinTrustData.dwUnionChoice = WTD_CHOICE_FILE;

    // Verify action.
    WinTrustData.dwStateAction = WTD_STATEACTION_VERIFY;

    // Verification sets this value.
    WinTrustData.hWVTStateData = NULL;

    // Not used.
    WinTrustData.pwszURLReference = NULL;

    // This is not applicable if there is no UI because it changes 
    // the UI to accommodate running applications instead of 
    // installing applications.
    WinTrustData.dwUIContext = 0;

    // Set pFile.
    WinTrustData.pFile = &FileData;

    // WinVerifyTrust verifies signatures as specified by the GUID 
    // and Wintrust_Data.
    lStatus = WinVerifyTrust(
        NULL,
        &WVTPolicyGUID,
        &WinTrustData);

    switch (lStatus) 
    {
        case ERROR_SUCCESS:
            /*
            Signed file:
                - Hash that represents the subject is trusted.

                - Trusted publisher without any verification errors.

                - UI was disabled in dwUIChoice. No publisher or 
                    time stamp chain errors.

                - UI was enabled in dwUIChoice and the user clicked 
                    "Yes" when asked to install and run the signed 
                    subject.
            */
            wprintf_s(L"The file \"%s\" is signed and the signature "
                L"was verified.\n",
                pwszSourceFile);
            break;

        case TRUST_E_NOSIGNATURE:
            // The file was not signed or had a signature 
            // that was not valid.

            // Get the reason for no signature.
            dwLastError = GetLastError();
            if (TRUST_E_NOSIGNATURE == dwLastError ||
                    TRUST_E_SUBJECT_FORM_UNKNOWN == dwLastError ||
                    TRUST_E_PROVIDER_UNKNOWN == dwLastError) 
            {
                // The file was not signed.
                wprintf_s(L"The file \"%s\" is not signed.\n",
                    pwszSourceFile);
            } 
            else 
            {
                // The signature was not valid or there was an error 
                // opening the file.
                wprintf_s(L"An unknown error occurred trying to "
                    L"verify the signature of the \"%s\" file.\n",
                    pwszSourceFile);
            }

            break;

        case TRUST_E_EXPLICIT_DISTRUST:
            // The hash that represents the subject or the publisher 
            // is not allowed by the admin or user.
            wprintf_s(L"The signature is present, but specifically "
                L"disallowed.\n");
            break;

        case TRUST_E_SUBJECT_NOT_TRUSTED:
            // The user clicked "No" when asked to install and run.
            wprintf_s(L"The signature is present, but not "
                L"trusted.\n");
            break;

        case CRYPT_E_SECURITY_SETTINGS:

            wprintf_s(L"CRYPT_E_SECURITY_SETTINGS - The hash "
                L"representing the subject or the publisher wasn't "
                L"explicitly trusted by the admin and admin policy "
                L"has disabled user trust. No signature, publisher "
                L"or timestamp errors.\n");
            break;

        default:

            wprintf_s(L"Error is: 0x%x.\n",
                lStatus);
            break;
    }

    // Any hWVTStateData must be released by a call with close.
    WinTrustData.dwStateAction = WTD_STATEACTION_CLOSE;

    lStatus = WinVerifyTrust(
        NULL,
        &WVTPolicyGUID,
        &WinTrustData);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please see [MSDN documentation on WinVerifyTrust](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388205(v=vs.85).aspx), it seems you will need to prevent retrieval of revocation lists as well:

```
// Use only the local cache for revocation checks. Prevents revocation checks over the network. 
WinTrustData.dwProvFlags = WTD_CACHE_ONLY_URL_RETRIEVAL;
```